# How can I convert my website to Application?

Tags: android, wordpress, native

I want to convert My wordpress Website into a Mobile APP. I want a app where user login once and than stay logged in unless he log out himself.

I have tried many site but didn't find the solution.

Comment: Your question is very broad, for authentication specifically you can use Firebase Authentication which allows storing the user session data. This helps to identify whether the user is already logged in or not.

Comment: you can wrap your web in capacitorjs and make native app. 
https://capacitorjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Wordpress plugin like [Androapp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/androapp/) to do the conversion for you. However, if you're looking for a quality app I would not recommend a conversion tool for your website, but actually building out an app either through a low/no-code app builder or learning app development.